# Adding both javascript handler and an asp.net code-behind handler to a control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

So if I add a code-behind event to a texbox e.g.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Blah" class="form-control" runat="server" OnTextChanged="Blah_TextChanged" 
    AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

That'll resolve to something like:

```
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$Blah" type="text"
    onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$MainContent$Blah\',\'\')', 0)" 
    onkeypress="if (WebForm_TextBoxKeyHandler(event) == false) return false;" 
    id="ctl00_MainContent_Blah" class="form-control">
```

But I also want to add a piece of js that will run before the event is fired in the codebehind.

Can I actually do this? And how?

I'm trying compounding events like you do with classes but no idea if I'm on the right lines e.g.

```
 OnTextChanged="Blah_TextChanged AlsoJavaScript()"
```

Where `AlsoJavaScript` is a function defined at the top of the page:

```
<script>function AlsoJavaScript(){alert('bing')};</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an event listener for Blah and remove onTextChanged from your HTML, that would give you the flexibility to run functions in the order you want them to...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#Blah").change(function(){
    functionA();
    functionB();

    // etc
  });
});
```